# Prove that the differentiation operator on the real vector space of polynomials of degree at most $n$ is nilpotent.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $P$ be the real vector space of polynomials $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n$ of degree at most $n$, and let $D$ denote the derivative $\frac{d}{dx}$, considered as a linear operator on $P$.

$\mathit{(a).}$ Prove that $D$ is a nilpotent operator, meaning that $D^k=0$ for sufficiently large $k$.

The differentiation operator $D: P \to P$ is nilpotent because the $(n+1)$ derivative of any polynomial of degree at most $n$ equals $0$. Thus for $k=n+1$, the operator $D^{n+1}=0$ for every $p(x) \in P$.

I wrote down a brief justification, but I feel like I haven't really proved that $D$ is nilpotent. Is my argument okay? This fact that $D$ is nilpotent seems fairly obvious, but I'm not sure if I'm missing any details

Comment: I don't think you're missing something.

Comment: It's fine for me.

Comment: The third paragraph in your question is a perfectly valid proof. Of course, if you want to be extremely explicit, you can use induction to show that the $(n+1)$-th derivative of a degree $n$ polynomial is $0$.

Comment: I also wanted to add, where maybe this is overkill [?], that $\mathcal{B}=\big\{1,x,x^{2},...,x^{n}\big\}\subset P$ is an ordered basis. Furthermore, for each $0\leq k\leq n$, we have that $D^{n+1}(x^{k})=0_{P}$ as you elegantly stated above (where $0_{P}$ is the zero polynomial/element of $P$).