# Derivative is a nilpotent operator

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I've been given an exercise as follows:

Let $P$ be the real vector space of polynomials of degree at most $n$, and let $D$ denote the derivative, considered as a linear operator on $P$. Prove that $D$ is a nilpotent operator, meaning that $D^k = 0$ for sufficiently large $k$.

Right now, I basically have a proof that says something like "since the polynomials in $P$ have a degree of at most $n$, $n + 1$ applications of $D$ will leave any polynomial in $P$ equal to $0$". However, this doesn't sound very rigorous to me, and I feel like a proof by induction may be involved. Could somebody please give me some feedback on this? Thank you very much!

P.S. I know that this question has been answered here to some extent already, but I haven't found anything on the induction part, which is why I'm asking this question now. Thanks again!

Comment: You have any ideas on how to use induction or over what? Can you please tell.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1620292/prove-that-the-differentiation-operator-on-the-real-vector-space-of-polynomials).

Comment: @Rick I guess induction would be used over the $n+1$ applications of $D$, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: ok since the question is marked duplicate I cannot answer it. However, I would like to give you some idea of my own. Try inducting on this property of differentiation. Assume true for a polynomial of degree $n$ and try to show for a polynomial of degree $n+1$.  Clearly base case is true i.e. when $p(x) = ax, D^2(p(x)) = 0$. Proceed from here and see if it works.

Comment: @DavidNiu Perhaps you'll begin to think what happens when you differentiate twice a linear polynomial, or thrice a quadratic polynomial, or four times a cubic pol.,..., or $\;n+1\;$ times a polynomial of degree $\;n\;$ ...?

Comment: @Rick Oh, I see now! For some reason I was thinking of starting right at the polynomial of degree $k$ and 'working my way down' to $0$, I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidNiu Great to know it helped. :)

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, I do have a solid conceptual idea of differentiating $n + 1$ times, but I didn't quite get how to put that into induction. Thanks though!